# Trying to read text in chunks and load it in list butget error

Tags: python, pandas, text

I have problem reading big csv file by chunks, and receive error by unknown reason for me.

Here is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
reader=pd.read_csv("C:\file.csv",sep='\t',chunksize=1)
sl=[]
for chunk in reader:
    chunk.append(sl)
```

Error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It should be `sl.append(chunk)`

Comment: always show full `Traceback` in question.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that "chunk.append(sl)" need to be "sl.append(chunk)"

```
import pandas as pd
reader=pd.read_csv("C:\file.csv",sep='\t',chunksize=1)
sl=[]
for chunk in reader:
    sl.append(chunk)
```